# Can I use pytest's assert unpacking in for running normal applications?

Tags: python, pytest, assert

Standard Python just raises an exception but doesn't show the mismatching values that caused an `assert` statement to fail. Pytest, as probably other testing frameworks as well, nicely unpacks the values of the assert statement to show what the problem was. Is there a way to patch this behavior that is available to unit tests into my normal python program, for example using `sys.excepthook`?

Comment: see https://pybites.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/behind-scenes-of-pytests-new-assertion.html

Comment: I think it's pretty difficult since this functionality is embedded within pytest itself. It's using importhooks to 'rewrite' the asserts, pretty cool stuff, but also advanced python.

Comment: source here:  https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py .... good luck!